# passing values into functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure why the code below is not working. It should take in a string and convert a G to a C and an A to a T and vice versa. However, it collects the input string but doesn't provide any output i.e. the alert just says "here is your reverse complement DNA"

```
var dnaSequence = prompt("Enter your DNA sequence here", "");
var newSequence = reverseComplement(dnaSequence);
alert("here is your reverse complemented DNA: " + newSequence);

function reverseComplement(dnaString) {

    var reverseC = [];
    var dnaArr = dnaString.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < dnaArr.length; i++) {

        switch (dnaArr[i]) {
            case 'A':
                reverseC.push('T');
                break;
            case 'T':
                reverseC.push('A');
                break;
            case 'C':
                reverseC.push('G');
                break;
            case 'G':
                reverseC.push('C');
                break;
        }
    }

    // Reverse and rejoin the the string    
    return reverseC.reverse().join('');
}
```

Comment: Because data in the prompt is empty

Comment: The code you posted works fine.

Comment: Your code works. Just make sure the input is in caps, and note that letters besides for A, T, C and G aren't being added to reverseC. Perhaps you should change that?

Comment: Do you need to change letters and then reverse the string? or just change letters and not reverse the result?

Comment: Thanks -  It was the case sensitivity - doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should take in a string and convert a G to a C and an A to a T and vice versa.

Then you don't need the reverse(), because you are pushing in order.

Also, Make sure that you are entering uppercase letters into the prompt.
Else, you can force the uppercase.

This is the code with the two fixes:

```
function reverseComplement(dnaString) {

    var reverseC = [];
    var dnaArr = dnaString.toUpperCase().split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < dnaArr.length; i++) {

        switch (dnaArr[i]) {
            case 'A':
                reverseC.push('T');
              break;
            case 'T':
                reverseC.push('A');
                break;
            case 'C':
                reverseC.push('G');
                break;
            case 'G':
                reverseC.push('C');
                break;
        }
    }

    // Reverse and rejoin the the string    
    return reverseC.join('');
}

var dnaSequence = prompt("Enter your DNA sequence here", "");
var newSequence = reverseComplement(dnaSequence);
alert("here is your reverse complemented DNA: " + newSequence);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary in JavaScript. Function declarations are treated as if the appeared at the start of the lexical unit, regardless of where they actually appear.

Comment: There's no need to define it at the top. Functions get moved up to the top anyway. But yes, the code works fine. Just make sure the input is caps

Answer (score 0):

The main lesson you need here is how to test and debug your JavaScript code.

First, get familiar with the JavaScript debugger in your browser. Instead of wondering why your code doesn't work, you can see directly what it is doing. Every modern browser has built-in JavaScript debugging tools; for example here is an [introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Second, when you are testing a function like this, don't use `prompt()` or `alert()`. Instead, provide a hard coded input string and use `console.log()` to display the output in the JavaScript debug console. This way you can run the same test case repeatedly. After you get one test case to work, you can add others.

There are several JavaScript testing frameworks if you want to get fancy, but to start with, simply using a hard coded input and `console.log()` output plus inspection in the JavaScript debugger is fine.

To make it easy to debug a function when you first write it, add a `debugger;` statement at the beginning. Then it will stop in the debugger and you can single-step through the code to see which parts of your function actually get executed and what all your variable values are at each step of the way.

For example (since it sounds like you were mistakenly testing with lowercase input), you might do this:

```
var dnaSequence = 'actg';
var newSequence = reverseComplement(dnaSequence);
console.log(newSequence);

function reverseComplement(dnaString) {
    debugger;

    var reverseC = [];
    var dnaArr = dnaString.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < dnaArr.length; i++) {

        switch (dnaArr[i]) {
            case 'A':
                reverseC.push('T');
                break;
            case 'T':
                reverseC.push('A');
                break;
            case 'C':
                reverseC.push('G');
                break;
            case 'G':
                reverseC.push('C');
                break;
        }
    }

    // Reverse and rejoin the the string    
    return reverseC.reverse().join('');
}
```

Now, if you have the DevTools open, it will stop in the debugger at the first line of your function. You can single-step through the function to see which of the `case` statements it actually goes to, and you will see that it doesn't go to any of them. You can also look at the value of `dnaArr[i]` and see whether it matches any of the `case` values.